# How to rewrite some part of the URL?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have some image thumb code like below on my website coming from third party website to my website

```
<div class="thumb"><img src="//www.abc.com/website/thumbs/461/beautifulimage/test1a.jpg" rel="//www.abc.com/website/thumbs/461/beautifulimage/test1a.jpg"></div>
```

I want to replace URL from

```
//www.abc.com/website/thumbs/461
```

to

```
//www.abc.com/website/thumbs/800
```

So, How I can replace URL on page load so it'll load code something like below

```
<div class="thumb"><img src="//www.abc.com/website/thumbs/800/beautifulimage/test1a.jpg" rel="//www.abc.com/website/thumbs/800/beautifulimage/test1a.jpg"></div>
```

Is there any way where I can call URL like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it is matter of changing `461` to `800` in Image thumbnail URL. This can be solved easily with jQuery. Just iterate over all the thumbnail images and replace `/461/` with `/800/`.

This has to be done after document is ready, and this is how you can do it.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.thumb img').each(function(index){
       var urlpath=$(this).attr('src');
       urlpath=urlpath.replace("/461/", "/800/");
       $(this).attr('src',urlpath);
    });
});
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/

We have used [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) jQuery function iterate over all the thumbnail images and used [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) jQuery function for setting and getting the `src` of image element.

Comment: Any Idea how to implement same into the wordpress I have used as 'jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.thumb img').each(function(index){
       var urlpath=$(this).attr('src');
       urlpath=urlpath.replace("/thumbs/461/", "/images/");
       $(this).attr('src',urlpath);
    });
});'